# I need my jQuery arrays on my server side Java

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, jsp

I'm working on a project and it requires me to create a JSP, get the arrays from afromentioned JSP and create an excel and a PDF from those arrays while saving those on Dropbox running on my server. I pretty much got everything working, but me being new with JSP and jQuery I really can't figure out an easy way of getting those arrays to Java. I could share my code both for the server and the JSP, but figured they weren't needed as the only part I need help with is sending 3 jQuery arrays to Java and that part is pretty much completely missing.

Thanks in advance and I hope everyone is having a good day!

Comment: With _jQuery arrays_ you mean JavaScript arrays? I think a good solution would be a HTML form that POST your values to the server. If you google _JSP form post_ there are plenty of tutorials.

Comment: use json, you'd send the json between apps, and decode the json where necessary. welcome to programming by the way. you'll love it

Comment: Thanks @zuckerburg for the warm welcome. Can you explain the JSON part a little. I saw some stuff about it before while searching but couldn't get it to work as I don't know how to exactly use it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In client side you need ajax request.

```
var jsonData=[12,11,13,16,17,18,19];
var ajaxOptions={
    url:"myUrl",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: {MyJSONArray:jsonData},
    success:function(data){
        // codes....
    },
}
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

and server side you can fetch it using getParameterValues

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("MyJSONArray[]");
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen this a lot of places but like I've said, I'm a little new to programming and have no idea what url:"myUrl" part is supposed to mean. Can you elaborate a little bit in that part please. Thanks!

Comment: "myUrl" should be replaced with your JSP/servlet URL which can handle the POST request.

Comment: God bless both of you and let me put this straight I don't even believe in him. I got it working now and I can't thank you people enough.

Comment: @NegiRox I actually did but my rep is below 15 and it doesn't show. Just in case I tried to upvote again though.